# Probability dogs

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are 15 dogs in an obedience class. Five of the dogs are Dalmatians. Aside from that, the rest are
all different breeds. Assume that the instructor can only distinguish between the dogs by their breeds.
(In other words, he can’t tell the Dalmatians apart!) At the beginning of class all of the dogs are lined
up in a row.

a. As far as the instructor can tell, how many ways can the dogs be lined up in a row? (Remember, the Dalmations are indistinguishable.)

-> This would be 15! if all the dogs were distinct but I don't know how to account for the fact that the Dalmations are indistinguishable. Do I just consider a block of 5 dalmatians as 1? Would that make the probability 11!?

b. Assume that the dogs are given sweaters that completely disguise what breed they are. 3 wear
yellow sweaters, 4 wear red sweaters, 3 wear blue sweaters, and 5 wear green sweaters. At this
point, the instructor can only distinguish between the dogs by their sweater colors. (In other words,
all the dogs with the same color sweater look alike to him!) As far as the instructor can tell, how
many ways can the dogs be lined up in a row?

-> Placing yellow sweater dogs is 15 choose 3. Placing red is 12 choose 4. Placing blue is 8 choose 3 and green is 5 choose 5 right? And then I can multiply all those to find the ways to line the dogs up?

c. Assume the sweater scenario in part (b). What is the probability that the instructor sees all of the
dogs with the same sweater color sitting next to each other (for example: RRRRYYYGGGGGBBB)?

-> I have no idea how to do this one.

Help appreciated

Comment: Isn't (c) $4!$ out of "the answer of (b)" cases?

Answer (score 0):

a) divide $15!$ by the number of arrangements of the 5 dalmations

b) you are correct.

c) there are $15!$ equally probable ways of lining up 15 distinct dogs.
the number of these that fit into the scheme RRRRYYYGGGGGBBB is

$ 4!3!5!3! $

Comment: @Sammy : For part (c) WW1 gives you the count of arrangements of dogs *within* their blocks of colours.  Don't forget you must also account for all other such arrangements *of* the four blocks: $\color{brown}{YYY}\color{red}{RRRR}\color{green}{GGGGG}\color{blue}{BBB}$, $\color{green}{GGGGG}\color{red}{RRRR}\color{navy}{BBB}\color{brown}{YYY}$, and so forth.

Comment: that is correct , I was just showing the one example.

Comment: @GrahamKemp There would be 4! different arrangements of such blocks right? So just multiply 4!3!5!3! by 4!?

Comment: $\color{green}{\checkmark}$ @Sammy.